# Automatic FTP deploy: is there any automatic / programmable tool available?

Tags: ftp, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I need this

- Watch a dir content
- When dir content change

  - delete a specific ftp folder
  - upload all dir content to the same ftp folder

I'm totally unaware of best way to accomplish this task.

I'm looking for suggestions / ideas.... gulp? grunt? node? nope :) ?

Actually I know no build tools. So before try/fault with every single options I ask you for suggestions.

EDIT: Please take note that I'm asking for a Continuos Deployment tool able to watch for file changes and to upload to FTP.

I cannot choose to change FTP ... I'd only change job

Comment: Why not just upload the modified files? It would be quicker than uploading an entire folder when a single file is modified.

Comment: @RayRadin: no problem, it's better, but... which tool can handle this autodeployment?

Comment: Watching content changes: `inotifywait`; authentication on remote machine: `ssh`; file synchronization: `rsync`, recipe is in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/339241. All that combined together is called [`lsyncd`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-mirror-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps-with-lsyncd#how-to-configure-remote-syncing-with-lsyncd).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a Continuous Deployment solution. FTP is not necessarily what needs to be done. You haven't mentioned a technology stack, but if you were (for example) working in Visual Studio, you can easily setup continuous deployment to an app service through Azure integrations. That way, whenever you have the project open in VS, if you make code changes and save them they are uploaded to your app.

[You can read about app service CD on Azure here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment)

There are, of course, many different continuous deployment solutions available to you. This was a specific example I'm a little more well versed with. [Here is a list of other solutions, each with their own sets of functionality.](https://xebialabs.com/the-ultimate-devops-tool-chest/deployment/) If you do your research, I'm sure you'll find what you need (rather than write a script to do the directory monitoring and FTP for you)

Comment: "Continuous Deployment solution": OK, exactly

"FTP is not necessarily". this is the problem... In year 2017, FTP deployment is TO AVOID, but I cannot choose this ... we ONLY have a shared host service so I see only FTP as real deployment solution

This is the source of the question: "It's a disaster waiting to happeng" ... uploading single folders and/or files in a very big code tree could bring to every possible inconsistent code state .... 

SO: I need a CD tool which can manage FTP as final deployment channel

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your requirements. FTP can be the end result while using a CD solution... any CD solution you choose has to upload files to a server when new files are present right? How do you think that gets done? Probably FTP behind the scenes. What about your "shared host service" makes it not possible to setup CD?

Answer (score 0):

The user case you have described is unique, thus you will not find an already build solution where you can simple run it and be done. You will need to create your own.

**Watch directory.**

This can be translated into "your code needs to be aware of file upload". This can be achieved via "notification" being *pushed* onto your code or your code *pulls* "notification" on its own.

Sadly, *push* from FTP Server will not work, as (to my knowledge) no FTP Server supports a push notification on file upload. To understand what I mean here, think of SVN post-commit hook.

The easiest to make *pull* is to *tail* FTP Log and look for *STOR* command, match your watch directory (via regexp) and on match execute bash/PHP or any other script to make **step (2)**. **Step (2)** is a handful of ftp client commands.

For PHP:

- Remove directory: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rmdir.php
- Upload a file (in comments there are recursive examples to upload directory and
  it's content): http://ee.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php